Setting the position of the line in the window does not work when using Fyne
I'm using canvas to draw a line on the window, changing its position before the first drawing, but it didn't work. Here is the code:
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
    "image/color"
)

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    w := myApp.NewWindow("Line")

    line := canvas.NewLine(color.White)
    line.StrokeWidth = 3

    //line.Position1 = fyne.NewPos(10, 10) // Equally ineffective
    //line.Position2 = fyne.NewPos(100, 100) // Equally ineffective

    line.Move(fyne.NewPos(10, 10))
    line.Resize(fyne.NewSize(100, 100))

    w.SetContent(line)
    w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(300, 300))

    w.ShowAndRun()
}

The expected result should look like this:

But in practice the position remains the default:

However, there is no problem when using goroutine for delayed modifications:
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
    "image/color"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    w := myApp.NewWindow("Line")

    line := canvas.NewLine(color.White)
    line.StrokeWidth = 3

    w.SetContent(line)
    w.Resize(fyne.NewSize(300, 300))

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3) // After 3 seconds, the line successfully changed from the default position to the specified position
        line.Move(fyne.NewPos(10, 10))
        line.Resize(fyne.NewSize(100, 100))
    }()

    w.ShowAndRun()
}


I don't know if it's Fyne's bug or my way of using it.
My goal is to draw the line in the specified position when the window is first drawn.
Note: I use Windows and go1.22
// Sorry about my English.

The item at the top of a window will always be told to fill it - like the contents of a Stack container.
To move items manually you should put them in a container with no layout (container.NewWithoutLayout). Any other arrangement will be laid out for you (and a line by default draws from top left to bottom right of the space).
By using the goroutine you seem to be sneaking past the window layout, but the next time it is refreshed or resized the line would snap back to full size.
